# Read TFS checkin comments using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs

Using Jenkins Job, I want to read the TFS (around 2008 version) check-in comment and based on that comment i need to perform some more action items in the Jenkins build definition.

Comment: TFS 2008 is quite old and out of support for  a long time. Suggest you update your TFS version to get new features and continued assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Team explorer everywhere which is a command line utility for TFS. you need to install that on your Jenkins server and use the command as below:

tf -h
Team Explorer Everywhere Command Line Client (version 14.0.3.201603291047)

Available commands and their options:

```
      add         [-lock:none|checkin|checkout] [-type:<value>] [-recursive] [-silent] [-noignore] <localItemSpec>...
      branch      [-version:<value>] [-noget] [-lock:none|checkin|checkout] [-recursive] [-checkin] [-comment:<value>|@valuefile] [-author:<value>]
          [-notes:"note"="value"[;"note2"="value2"[;...]]|@notefile] <oldItemSpec> <newLocalItem>
      branches    [-version:<value>] <itemSpec>...
      changeset   [-latest] [-comment:<value>|@valuefile] [-notes:"note"="value"[;"note2"="value2"[;...]]|@notefile] [changenumber]
      checkin     [-all] [-author:<value>] [-comment:<value>|@valuefile] [-notes:"note"="value"[;"note2"="value2"[;...]]|@notefile] [-override:<value>|@valuefile]
          [-recursive] [-validate] [-bypass] [-force] [-noautoresolve] [-associate:<workItemID>[,<workItemID>...]] [-resolve:<workItemID>[,<workItemID>...]]
          [-saved] [<itemSpec>...]
     checkout    [-recursive] [-lock:none|checkin|checkout] [-type:<value>] <itemSpec>...
     delete      [-lock:none|checkin|checkout] [-recursive] <itemSpec>...
     delete      -detect [-lock:none|checkin|checkout] [-recursive]
     destroy     [-keephistory] [-startcleanup] [-preview] [-silent] [-stopat:<value>] [-noprompt] itemspec1[;versionspec][;XdeletionID] [itemspec2...itemspecN]
     difference  [-recursive] <itemSpec> <itemSpec2>
     difference  [-shelveset:<value>] [-recursive] <shelvesetItemSpec>
     difference  [-version:<value>] [-recursive] <itemSpec>
```